# How do I get Greasemonkey to click on a button that only appears after a delay?

Tags: javascript, button, click, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I've seen a lot of similar questions and I've tried everything I can think of to get this to work on my own.

First the relevant code (¿from the target page?):

```
document.getElementById('btn_submit').innerHTML =
 '<input type="hidden" value="17271" name="idofclick">
  <input type="submit" value=" Click Me Now! " name="submit_com" class="padding2">';
```

Basically there is a timer on the page and the "click me now!" button appears after 3 secs, that's the part I want to click on.

This is my code. It's not working:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        abc
// @namespace   something
// @description abc Scripty
// @include     *
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
(function ClicktheButton(obj) {
   var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
   evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
   var canceled = !obj.dispatchEvent(evt);
   /*

  if(canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault
    alert("not canceled");
  }
  */
}

var StupidButton = document.querySelector.innerHTML('input[type="submit"][value=" Click Me Now! "]');
ClicktheButton(StupidButton);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code has errors.  Use Firefox's error console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) to see them.  Using [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) to check your code, can be helpful too.

Anyway, this is a common Greasemonkey problem.  Use [the waitForKeyElements() utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891) to handle the delayed appearance of that button.  Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to simplify the code (and make it more robust and portable).

So your script would become:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

function clickSubmitBtnWhenItAppears (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}

//-- Value match is case-sensitive
waitForKeyElements (
    //"#btn_submit input[type='submit'][value*='Click Me Now']",
    "input[type='submit'][value*='Click Me Now']",
    clickSubmitBtnWhenItAppears
);
```

Comment: hmm that doesn't seem to be working either is it because there is a space between ' and Click Me Now! ' ?

Comment: No, that's not it.  The `value*=` operator is [a "contains" selector](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=attribute-contains-selector).  So, as long as `Click Me Now` is **exact**, then it will work.  Try the updated code, and if that doesn't work, post the exact, unedited HTML of element with the id `btn_submit`.